# CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX/CATALOG statement cannot be used inside a user transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, transactions, full-text-search

I have a db versioning app to update deployed databases. It runs smoothly with almost all SQL statements but when I decided to use FullText Search  and generated scripts to use statements like following it broke.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [ProductCatalog]

--Create fulltext index on Product
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [tblProduct] KEY INDEX [PK_Catalog]
    ON ([ProductCatalog]) WITH (CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO)
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [tblProduct] ADD ([ProductName] LANGUAGE [English])
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [tblProduct] ENABLE
```

I use the following code to execute SQL file within a C# SqlTransaction

```
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("cstring");
SqlTransaction trn = cnn.BeginTransaction();

cnn.Open();

using (SqlCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = cnn;       
    cmd.Transaction = trn;

    cmd.CommandText = SQLScript;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

trn.Commit();        
cnn.Close();
```

How can I run my scripts without a transaction?

Comment: If I understand clearly what you trying, just comment this line: cmd.Transaction = trn;

Comment: @Keith sorry it was mistyped when editing the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've modified my code to execute scripts

```
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("cstring");
SqlTransaction trn = null;

cnn.Open();

using (SqlCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = cnn;

    if(!SQLScript.Contains("FULLTEXT"))
    {
        trn = cnn.BeginTransaction();
        cmd.Transaction = trn;
    }        

    cmd.CommandText = SQLScript;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

if(trn!=null)
    trn.Commit();

cnn.Close();
```